# Not getting output in SparkStreaming

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I'm using spark streaming api to comsume XML message and produce output.

Here is my code

package sparkProject;

```
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.util.*;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.FlatMapFunction;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder;
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.RowEncoder;
import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQuery;
import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryException;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataTypes;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType;

import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.RowFactory;

public class XMLSparkStreamEntry {

    static StructType structType = new StructType();

    static {
        structType = structType.add("FirstName", DataTypes.StringType, false);
        structType = structType.add("LastName", DataTypes.StringType, false);
        structType = structType.add("Title", DataTypes.StringType, false);
        structType = structType.add("ID", DataTypes.StringType, false);
        structType = structType.add("Division", DataTypes.StringType, false);
        structType = structType.add("Supervisor", DataTypes.StringType, false);

    }

    static ExpressionEncoder<Row> encoder = RowEncoder.apply(structType);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws StreamingQueryException {

        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf();
        SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().config(conf).appName("Spark Program").master("local[*]")
                .getOrCreate();

        Dataset<Row> ds1 = spark.readStream().format("kafka").option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
                .option("subscribe", "Kafkademo").load();

        Dataset<Row> ss = ds1.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)");

        Dataset<Row> finalOP = ss.flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<Row, Row>() {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public Iterator<Row> call(Row t) throws Exception {

                JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(FileWrapper.class);
                Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

                StringReader reader = new StringReader(t.getAs("value"));
                FileWrapper person = (FileWrapper) unmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);

                List<Employee> emp = new ArrayList<Employee>(person.getEmployees());
                List<Row> rows = new ArrayList<Row>();
                for (Employee e : emp) {

                    rows.add(RowFactory.create(e.getFirstname(), e.getLastname(), e.getTitle(), e.getId(),
                            e.getDivision(), e.getSupervisor()));

                }
                return rows.iterator();
            }
        }, encoder);


        Dataset<Row> wordCounts = finalOP.groupBy("FirstName").count();

        StreamingQuery query = wordCounts.writeStream().outputMode("complete").format("console").start();
        System.out.println("SHOW SCHEMA");
        query.awaitTermination();

    }

}
```

But In output am getting empty `count` and `FirstName`. If I comsume simple texts as messages, then I can see the output with word count. But in case of xml as message and parsing them, its not working and showing empty.

May I know please what am doing wrong here ?

Comment: What is your output with xml? I think, the thing you the most is to properly parse the xml.

Comment: @itwasntme, In output am just getting count and FirstName as name column names with no values in it.